# find duplicated values in array and return how many time or 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, numbers

i have an array of dates:

```
let arr = ['02-11-2022', '02-11-2022', '03-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '05-11-2022', '07-11-2022'];
```

i want to search which dates are duplicated and how much times?
and if date is skiped like 06-11-2022 so it will be 0 (like saving space).
return all that in new array like that:

```
let new = [2,1,3,1,0,1];
```

i want to save space so i could compare later:

```
arr[0] == new[0]...
arr[3] == new[3]...
arr[5] == new[5]...
```

i tried many function but couldnt save space or count it in the correct way.

thank you.

Comment: How would you compare `arr` and the new array when one of them just has numbers? I'm not getting the use case of this output

Comment: sounds like someone has homework.  I would suggest making a map.  You can reduce the array into a map where the key is the date then the values are how often there was an occurrence.

Comment: `date is skiped`  That question is actually the hard part, what if the date skipped is '01-11-2022`  or `08-11-2022`  can we assume the first array entry and last are always the first and last in what your looking at.  And even after knowing this your going to need to Date maths to work out when going past 28/29/30/31 days etc..

Comment: See response below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algorithm for this could be:

```
let arr = ['02-11-2022', '02-11-2022', '03-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '05-11-2022', '07-11-2022'];

const duplicates = [];

let currentDuplicates = 0;
let previousDate = arr[0].slice(0, 2);
while(arr.length) {
    const element = arr[0];
    
    arr = arr.filter((comparedElement) => {
        const isEqual = comparedElement === element;
        if (isEqual) {
            currentDuplicates += 1;
        }

        return !isEqual;
    });

    // the quantity of days between today and the last day is greater than 1
    const currentDay = element.slice(0, 2);
    const skippedDays = currentDay - previousDate;
    const hasSkippedDays = skippedDays > 1;

    if (hasSkippedDays) {
        duplicates.push(...'0'.repeat(skippedDays - 1).split('').map((n) => Number(n)));
    }

    duplicates.push(currentDuplicates);
    currentDuplicates = 0;
    previousDate = currentDay;
}
```

While the array has an element, we filter and, at the same time, count how many times we finded an element equal to our current element. And before we push the duplicate into the array, we check how many days passed between today and the last parsed day.

This is how my brain instinctively thinks, so I would try to refactor for more performance gains!

An observation too, is that the code only compares the number of days between two dates, so if you skip a month or a yearlike `let arr = ['01-01-2000', '01-12-2000', '01-12-9999']` , it'll not recognize the skipped days :)

---

A quick built-in solution to find the total of duplicates could be getting the array length with the duplicates:

```
const arraySize = arr.length;
```

Transform the array in a set. Sets by nature doesn't allow duplicates, then you just need to find the difference between the two lengths:

```
const set = new Set(arr);
const totalDuplicates = arraySize - set.size;
```

Comment: The OP really needs to divide his question into two.  As your now the 4th poster to totally ignore `and if date is skiped`

Comment: I noticed just after I posted the answer! Thanks for the heads up, I edited the answer with a draft solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const dateCount = {};
const dates = ['02-11-2022', '02-11-2022', '03-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '05-11-2022', '07-11-2022'];
dates.forEach((date) => {
    dateCount[date] = (dateCount[date] || 0) + 1;
})

console.log(dateCount)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have something like this to count duplicates in your array:

```
const dateCounter = (dates) => {

  const dateObjects = dates.map(dateString => {
    const parts = dateString.split('-');
    const [day, month, year] = [parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]];
    return new Date(`${month}/${day}/${year}`);
  });

  const counts = {}
  const duplicates = []
  const missingDates = [];
 
  for (let i = 1; i < dateObjects.length; i++) {
    const diff = dateObjects[i].getTime() - dateObjects[i - 1].getTime();

    if (diff > 86400000) {
      const numMissingDates = Math.floor(diff / 86400000) - 1;
      for (let j = 1; j <= numMissingDates; j++) {
        const missingDate = new Date(dateObjects[i - 1].getTime() + (j * 86400000))
        missingDates.push(missingDate);
        counts[missingDate] = 0
      }
    } 
     
    counts[dateObjects[i]] = i !== 1 ? (counts[dateObjects[i]] || 0) + 1 : (counts[dateObjects[i]] || 1) + 1;

  }

  for (const key in counts) {
     duplicates.push(counts[key]);
  }

  return duplicates

}
```

This is how you would execute it as an example:

```
const arr = ['02-11-2022', '02-11-2022', '03-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '04-11-2022', '05-11-2022', '07-11-2022'];
const duplicates = dateCounter(arr);
console.log(duplicates); // [2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: If you notice question is about counting the duplicates, the date is a secondary thing. I'll update it  shortly

Comment: There are plenty of questions about counting duplicates, in which this should be marked as duplicate.